# Not able to vote on questions, answers and comments in Stack Overflow

Tags: support, reputation, new-users, privileges

I just joined Stack Overflow today. I am not able to vote on other people's questions, answers and comments.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's the way the things works. Read http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: see also: http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges

Comment: Please take a few minutes to go through the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) pages in order to become familiar with how StackOverflow works, especially the part related to [privileges](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges). The short answer: You have to earn the privileges to vote and comment here by participating, so that you've spent enough time to understand what voting means and how comments are meant to be used. If you don't know how the site works, and aren't willing to work enough to learn, you shouldn't vote.

Comment: Actually, I don't see any reason someone has to ask this question. You would not know you could not vote unless you tried clicking on the vote buttons. And once you click them, you are shown a message that tells you that you can't vote unless you have the reputation and the privileges.

Answer (score 9):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!

You're not doing anything "wrong," per se.

This site uses a [privilege system](//stackoverflow.com/help/privileges), which allow you to become more involved with the site as your [reputation](//stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) grows.

You are awarded the ["vote up"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) privilege at 15 reputation, and the ["vote down"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down) privilege at 125 reputation.

I'd suggest taking the [tour](//stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: yes, you get more involved with the site as your reputation grows. But let's consider that the site itself grows. Apart from new technology topics (this makes that questions will always arise).
Simply assume that 99 per cent of possible questions have become an answer. Almost nobody new to the site would ever be able to comment, vote or even ask a meta question. One could then be tempted to ask a question that's a bit silly...

Comment: In my case: I was willing to vote a good answer at unix.stackexchange. But I believe that I'll hardly ever ask a question regarding unix or linux (yes, because many questions are already posted). So I'll not be able to comment ever.
Because I can't even put the privilege system into discussion there, I intended to ask a meta question here, and found this existing question...